# Typescript - Pick only a value from another type's field

Tags: typescript

I have a type that I would like to pick only a value from one field. Type looks like this:

```
export interface RoleDto {
    id: string;
    objectNumber: string;
    roleType: "BA" | "BM" | "BP" | "FR" | "RM";
}
```

I would like to create a type from a type value in `RoleDto`:

```
export type IRoleType = Pick<RoleDto, "roleType">;
```

Which creates an initial type:

```
{ rolleType: "BA" | "BM" | "BP" | "FR" | "RM" }
```

But, I would like to get just a value so that I can use it for my component props like this:

```
export const RolleTag = ({ rolleType }: { rolleType: IRolleType }) => {
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: try `RoleDto['type']`   ?

Comment: After re-readig the problem, I cannot see where the problem is. The code seems to work as is: [Code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsA2EAiZ3IDeAUMmcsACYBcyAzmFKAOYDcp56ARgFYQJgAcgFcAtl2i0GTEGw5koWCABUAngAcItAEQAhAILbkAH2R6AskdN6AClbMAxVPe2pL7AL7FiYDSgCSGNhqmsgAvMg2wAgA1gA8Qbj4ADRmisF+2gB87N4I6CAMaErKcMzhyAAUhMjpKn7IHrSBJX4AlOFZZPmFSgB0mOjMlXUhEG3sPUV1OMoA8rSJeAQRhFQ6AIzaqdx8AiLikmZbqaN+OgbaXomlwzPzE0A). Is the problem in property rename (in your question IRoleType picks non-existing prop)?

Comment: After edit, it is almost clear, but `Pick<RoleDto, "roleType">` still picks non-existing property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to look up a specific property on another type

> ```ts
> type Person = { age: number; name: string; alive: boolean };
> type Age = Person["age"];
>     
> // type Age = number
> ```

```ts
interface RoleDto {
    id: string;
    objectNumber: string;
    roleType: "BA" | "BM" | "BP" | "FR" | "RM";
}

type IRoleType = Pick<RoleDto, "roleType">;
type IRoleTypeValues = IRoleType["roleType"];

const RoleTag = ({ rolleType }: { rolleType: IRoleTypeValues }) =>  console.log(rolleType);
const roleDTO: RoleDto = {id: "1", objectNumber: "1", roleType: "BA"}
RoleTag({rolleType: "BA"});
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsA2EAiZ3IDeAUMmcsACYBcyAzmFKAOYDcp56ARgFYQJgAcgFcAtl2i0GTEGw5koWCABUAngAcItAEQAhAILbkAH2R6AskdN6AClbMAxVPe2pL7AL7FiYDSgCSGNhqmsgAvMg2wAgA1gA8Qbj4ADRmisF+2gB87L6hgUohEABqcJjCEHThyAUZmgDa2ukqmQC67MQI6CAMaIVwzNUAFITI6XUoHrSj4y2atLVzJWUVVR4AlOFZZF09SgB0mOjMQ7NF6+y7vc04ygDytIl4BBGEVDoAjNqp3HwCIuJJGYvqlmkUdAZtF5EsoBiMzn4IYYNqxkEA)